# Magento 2.4 Admin invoices page spinner never disappear

Tags: magento2, grid, admin-panel, magento2.4.3

I want view a list of invoices in my mogento module. The data has successfully loaded, but the loading spinner never disappear.

Magento version: 2.4.3

OS version: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

[image]

My exception log:

```
[2021-09-23 16:10:15] main.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [position_category_4] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw","index":"magento2_product_1_v2"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento2_product_1_v2","node":"xKgAFkDJTWyBhshF12msYw","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [position_category_4] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw","index":"magento2_product_1_v2"}}]},"status":400} {"exception":"[object] (Elasticsearch\\Common\\Exceptions\\BadRequest400Exception(code: 400): {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"query_shard_exception\",\"reason\":\"No mapping found for [position_category_4] in order to sort on\",\"index_uuid\":\"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw\",\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v2\"}],\"type\":\"search_phase_execution_exception\",\"reason\":\"all shards failed\",\"phase\":\"query\",\"grouped\":true,\"failed_shards\":[{\"shard\":0,\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v2\",\"node\":\"xKgAFkDJTWyBhshF12msYw\",\"reason\":{\"type\":\"query_shard_exception\",\"reason\":\"No mapping found for [position_category_4] in order to sort on\",\"index_uuid\":\"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw\",\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v2\"}}]},\"status\":400} at /home/vagrant/magento/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:675)"} []
[2021-09-23 16:18:15] main.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [position_category_7] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw","index":"magento2_product_1_v2"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento2_product_1_v2","node":"xKgAFkDJTWyBhshF12msYw","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [position_category_7] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw","index":"magento2_product_1_v2"}}]},"status":400} {"exception":"[object] (Elasticsearch\\Common\\Exceptions\\BadRequest400Exception(code: 400): {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"query_shard_exception\",\"reason\":\"No mapping found for [position_category_7] in order to sort on\",\"index_uuid\":\"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw\",\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v2\"}],\"type\":\"search_phase_execution_exception\",\"reason\":\"all shards failed\",\"phase\":\"query\",\"grouped\":true,\"failed_shards\":[{\"shard\":0,\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v2\",\"node\":\"xKgAFkDJTWyBhshF12msYw\",\"reason\":{\"type\":\"query_shard_exception\",\"reason\":\"No mapping found for [position_category_7] in order to sort on\",\"index_uuid\":\"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw\",\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v2\"}}]},\"status\":400} at /home/vagrant/magento/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:675)"} []
[2021-09-23 16:24:21] main.ERROR: Unable to send mail: Unknown error {"exception":"[object] (Laminas\\Mail\\Transport\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable to send mail: Unknown error at /home/vagrant/magento/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Transport/Sendmail.php:298)"} []
[2021-09-23 16:24:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to send mail. Please try again later. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\MailException(code: 0): Unable to send mail. Please try again later. at /home/vagrant/magento/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Transport.php:114)"} []
[2021-09-23 16:40:04] main.ERROR: Unable to send mail: Unknown error {"exception":"[object] (Laminas\\Mail\\Transport\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable to send mail: Unknown error at /home/vagrant/magento/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Transport/Sendmail.php:298)"} []
[2021-09-23 16:40:05] main.ERROR: Unable to send mail: Unknown error {"exception":"[object] (Laminas\\Mail\\Transport\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable to send mail: Unknown error at /home/vagrant/magento/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Transport/Sendmail.php:298)"} []
[2021-09-23 17:11:07] main.ERROR: Unable to send mail: Unknown error {"exception":"[object] (Laminas\\Mail\\Transport\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable to send mail: Unknown error at /home/vagrant/magento/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Transport/Sendmail.php:298)"} []
[2021-09-23 17:11:07] main.ERROR: Unable to send mail: Unknown error {"exception":"[object] (Laminas\\Mail\\Transport\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable to send mail: Unknown error at /home/vagrant/magento/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Transport/Sendmail.php:298)"} []
[2021-09-23 17:29:05] main.ERROR: Unable to send mail: Unknown error {"exception":"[object] (Laminas\\Mail\\Transport\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable to send mail: Unknown error at /home/vagrant/magento/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Transport/Sendmail.php:298)"} []
[2021-09-23 17:29:05] main.ERROR: Unable to send mail: Unknown error {"exception":"[object] (Laminas\\Mail\\Transport\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable to send mail: Unknown error at /home/vagrant/magento/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Transport/Sendmail.php:298)"} []
[2021-09-23 18:25:43] main.ERROR: Unable to send mail: Unknown error {"exception":"[object] (Laminas\\Mail\\Transport\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable to send mail: Unknown error at /home/vagrant/magento/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Transport/Sendmail.php:298)"} []
[2021-09-24 15:05:32] main.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [position_category_4] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw","index":"magento2_product_1_v2"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento2_product_1_v2","node":"xKgAFkDJTWyBhshF12msYw","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [position_category_4] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw","index":"magento2_product_1_v2"}}]},"status":400} {"exception":"[object] (Elasticsearch\\Common\\Exceptions\\BadRequest400Exception(code: 400): {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"query_shard_exception\",\"reason\":\"No mapping found for [position_category_4] in order to sort on\",\"index_uuid\":\"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw\",\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v2\"}],\"type\":\"search_phase_execution_exception\",\"reason\":\"all shards failed\",\"phase\":\"query\",\"grouped\":true,\"failed_shards\":[{\"shard\":0,\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v2\",\"node\":\"xKgAFkDJTWyBhshF12msYw\",\"reason\":{\"type\":\"query_shard_exception\",\"reason\":\"No mapping found for [position_category_4] in order to sort on\",\"index_uuid\":\"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw\",\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v2\"}}]},\"status\":400} at /home/vagrant/magento/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:675)"} []
[2021-09-24 15:05:35] main.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [position_category_5] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw","index":"magento2_product_1_v2"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento2_product_1_v2","node":"xKgAFkDJTWyBhshF12msYw","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [position_category_5] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw","index":"magento2_product_1_v2"}}]},"status":400} {"exception":"[object] (Elasticsearch\\Common\\Exceptions\\BadRequest400Exception(code: 400): {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"query_shard_exception\",\"reason\":\"No mapping found for [position_category_5] in order to sort on\",\"index_uuid\":\"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw\",\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v2\"}],\"type\":\"search_phase_execution_exception\",\"reason\":\"all shards failed\",\"phase\":\"query\",\"grouped\":true,\"failed_shards\":[{\"shard\":0,\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v2\",\"node\":\"xKgAFkDJTWyBhshF12msYw\",\"reason\":{\"type\":\"query_shard_exception\",\"reason\":\"No mapping found for [position_category_5] in order to sort on\",\"index_uuid\":\"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw\",\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v2\"}}]},\"status\":400} at /home/vagrant/magento/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:675)"} []
[2021-09-24 15:05:37] main.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [position_category_6] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw","index":"magento2_product_1_v2"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento2_product_1_v2","node":"xKgAFkDJTWyBhshF12msYw","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [position_category_6] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw","index":"magento2_product_1_v2"}}]},"status":400} {"exception":"[object] (Elasticsearch\\Common\\Exceptions\\BadRequest400Exception(code: 400): {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"query_shard_exception\",\"reason\":\"No mapping found for [position_category_6] in order to sort on\",\"index_uuid\":\"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw\",\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v2\"}],\"type\":\"search_phase_execution_exception\",\"reason\":\"all shards failed\",\"phase\":\"query\",\"grouped\":true,\"failed_shards\":[{\"shard\":0,\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v2\",\"node\":\"xKgAFkDJTWyBhshF12msYw\",\"reason\":{\"type\":\"query_shard_exception\",\"reason\":\"No mapping found for [position_category_6] in order to sort on\",\"index_uuid\":\"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw\",\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v2\"}}]},\"status\":400} at /home/vagrant/magento/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:675)"} []
[2021-09-24 15:05:41] main.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [position_category_7] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw","index":"magento2_product_1_v2"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento2_product_1_v2","node":"xKgAFkDJTWyBhshF12msYw","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [position_category_7] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw","index":"magento2_product_1_v2"}}]},"status":400} {"exception":"[object] (Elasticsearch\\Common\\Exceptions\\BadRequest400Exception(code: 400): {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"query_shard_exception\",\"reason\":\"No mapping found for [position_category_7] in order to sort on\",\"index_uuid\":\"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw\",\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v2\"}],\"type\":\"search_phase_execution_exception\",\"reason\":\"all shards failed\",\"phase\":\"query\",\"grouped\":true,\"failed_shards\":[{\"shard\":0,\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v2\",\"node\":\"xKgAFkDJTWyBhshF12msYw\",\"reason\":{\"type\":\"query_shard_exception\",\"reason\":\"No mapping found for [position_category_7] in order to sort on\",\"index_uuid\":\"JsIu4CR6TDu_7k5UDvXzKw\",\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v2\"}}]},\"status\":400} at /home/vagrant/magento/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:675)"} []
[2021-09-27 13:37:55] main.CRITICAL: No alive nodes found in your cluster {"exception":"[object] (Elasticsearch\\Common\\Exceptions\\NoNodesAvailableException(code: 0): No alive nodes found in your cluster at /home/vagrant/magento/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/ConnectionPool/StaticNoPingConnectionPool.php:64)"} []
[2021-09-27 14:52:40] main.ERROR: Unable to send mail: Unknown error {"exception":"[object] (Laminas\\Mail\\Transport\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable to send mail: Unknown error at /home/vagrant/magento/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Transport/Sendmail.php:298)"} []
[2021-09-27 14:53:18] main.ERROR: Unable to send mail: Unknown error {"exception":"[object] (Laminas\\Mail\\Transport\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable to send mail: Unknown error at /home/vagrant/magento/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Transport/Sendmail.php:298)"} []
[2021-09-27 14:55:15] main.ERROR: Unable to send mail: Unknown error {"exception":"[object] (Laminas\\Mail\\Transport\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable to send mail: Unknown error at /home/vagrant/magento/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Transport/Sendmail.php:298)"} []
```

Comment: Have you check the magento log file or console is there any error?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I added my exception log file. My console is running fine with no error reported.

Comment: Try to restart your elastic search and then check.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I tried. The spinner still won't go away. But this time if I flush the cache and then refresh the invoice page, the spinner will go away. But the next time I refresh the invoice page, the spinner still won't go away.